# Run GreenDao generator automatically everytime I build project with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, greendao, greendao-generator

I'm developing an Android app and I'm using greendao to model my database. I wanted to run the daogenerator everytime I rebuild a project but it is on another module.

How can I do this using gradle?

This is, how can I run the application in a module before building another module.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that!

1. Create a task that runs your generation. For my case the module with greendao is next to the app module. It is an java module.

   `task generateDao(type: GradleBuild) {
       dir = "../greendaogenerator"
       tasks = ["run"]
   }`
2. Configure that this task will run before every compile task

   `tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
       if (task.name.startsWith('compile')) {
           task.dependsOn generateDao
           task.mustRunAfter generateDao
       }
   }`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. When I try to use that it requires "bolts.Task". Is this really needed? Where can I get it? @qmar

Comment: @FábioCarballo this may be something specific to your project, please update the question with your project structure, it may be helpful for me to answer

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to comment:
qmar answer is the way to go. You just saved my day !
Perfectly works when your greendao implementation is a separate module inside your project.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Took quite some time to figure it out. Glad I could be helpful.